# Why are flat copper cables with holes used for high voltage ground?

Tags: voltage

I saw that a flat copper cable was used for the ground connection in a high voltage lab. I was wondering whats the difference as opposed to a normal cable ?

Comment: I would like to say reduced inductance, but that's usually in the context of a double-sided PCB (i.e. via stitching).

Comment: I can imagine a lot of things that people would name "flat copper cable with holes". Can you provide images? Or at least some drawings with dimensions?

Comment: Picture? How flat is flat? Was it run over, or do you mean a braided strap?

Comment: Its just a flat cable with holes that is exposed (no insulation), so I fail to see the reason behind it

Comment: What do you mean holes? As in there are random patches of insulation missing?

Comment: Is it these things you mean? http://www.copperbraid.co.uk/earth_strap.php

Comment: @Majenko , No its not like that. Imagine a rectangular solid copper strip with circles cut out every predetermined distance

Comment: You mean this? http://www.ck-supplies.com/uploads/ImageRoot/detail/12000/Zpv5kLTc.jpg

Answer (score 10):

Flat, semi-rigid metal strapping is sometimes used to electrically bond pieces of equipment together when they aren't expected to move significantly with respect to each other. A flat strap is easier to bend into shape than a round wire is, and doesn't require any specialized termination hardware. The holes are there so that it can be fastened to the equipment at each end with a screw or bolt.

[image: copper strap]
<sub>(source: [nibco.com](http://www.nibco.com/resources/products/600/623.jpg))</sub>

Comment: That seems to make sense, thank you. It is exactly that. Thank you very much

Comment: Flat tape is also nice because you can finish it nearly flush with a floor, so it does not become a tripping hazard.

Comment: Might the holes have a *secondary* purpose of allowing a wider strip at the same cost/weight (without increasing tear risk from thinning)?

Answer (score 5):

I work in high voltage in a high voltage lab for a living. There are several reasons why we use flat conductors for grounding, as well as carrying current in other situations. , Actually there are entire classes dedicated to explaining this, taught by physics and electrical engineering PhD types in their 80's, if you work in the field. Guys that are still around from the days of microwave tubes (not that microwave tubes have gone anywhere....)

Flat conductors tend to be braided and flexible, but not always, but then they are they are very easy to work with as far as routing. But the point is to get as low impedance as possible. The way you do that is through surface area. The more surface area in the conductor, the lower the impedance. It's the same for solid wire vs. stranded. A round conductor with the same impedance is going to be pretty fat and harder to route than a flat braided conductor.

Also there is what as know as "skin effect", where conductors tend to only really conduct at their surface skin. This effect increases with higher voltage and frequency, two things you'll probably see hand in hand in a HV Lab, especially one that deals in RF. The higher the surface area, the more skin, the lower the impedance to HV and RF.

Inductance is another factor. I see a lot of misinformed people who say the difference is minimal between round conductors and flat conductors as far as inductance goes. NOT TRUE! In high voltage and high frequencies, inductance has a huge impact on bad things like uncontrolled oscillation and noise. There are certain systems where you have huge high voltage power supplies operating devices that must have as low of a noise floor as possible. Flat cables can make all the difference, along with non-inductive resistors and the like.

In these labs and systems we don't just do stuff because "it's what was laying around in the parts bin". But if they are using strapping material like that, it's probably because that's what they had laying in the parts bin!
But like I say, there are a few well aged old physicists and electrical engineers out there that know all the math and are smarter than I am. that could tell you the deeper reasons "why"

Comment: No, skin effect is not a function of voltage.  Its depth depends on the material resistivity and the frequency.

Answer (score 0):

The electric equipment must be properly grounded, for that, its construction must be supported with a properly designed ground contact --- generally in a form of grounding bolt connected by a conducting circuit to the ground potential busbar/contour of the earthing system.  That form (bolt) of the grounding contact is predetermined by international (e.g. IEC) or local (e.g. IEEE, DIN, BS, GOST) technical regulation.

Therefore, such the cable (also why do you call this cable?, it is a wire because it has no termination and has only one and only conductor, i think it is more correct to call this shaped wire, or strip) is a convenient solution in that situation.  Other motivation was previously shown in full by Dave.